# Azure AD certificate based authentication: How do I specify the certificate path in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, x509certificate

I'm implementing **certificate based authentication flow through Node JS** for the first time, for an app hosted with Azure AD.

My goal is to generate `client_assertion` [(as documented here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate) based on `.pfx` certificates (X.509 format) that I've already uploaded to my AD app using App Service > TLS/SSL settings.

**Question**: How will my Node app refer the path of that certificate when it gets deployed on the server? What would be the correct relative path to it?

I am referring [this blog](https://medium.com/@ArsenVlad/certificate-based-auth-with-azure-service-principals-from-linux-command-line-a440c4599cae) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60531661/2163837). In both of these posts, certificate is stored locally, which is confusing for me, as I'm not sure how will that work after the deployment.
From above post:

```
var fs = require(‘fs’);
var cert = fs.readFileSync(‘key.pem’); //<-- how to use the AD app certificate path here?
```

Comment: Hi, any update this issue?

Comment: Hey thanks for the follow up, but the issue is I cannot keep the certificate on the same server, from security pov

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have uploaded the certificate in the portal, you still need to SFTP upload the certificate to a private folder on the server, then use the code below.

```
var cert = fs.readFileSync('path-to-private-folder/key.pem');
```

For more details, you could see this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692440/access-ssl-certificate-in-azure-web-app).