# Azure App Service Private Key Certificates no longer working in C# REST endpoint when replacing the X509 Certificate with unexpired one

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate

I had a working solution that has been in service for 1+ years.  On 4/8/2022, the certificate expired, and I got a new certificate from my Service Desk group.  I re-uploaded the certificate to my Azure App Service, and then realized I needed to re-deploy the code with the new Thumbprint.  I am uploading to the TLS/SSL settings Private Key Certificates (.pfx).

I re-deployed along with some debugging log lines, and it seems that StoreName.My + StoreLocation.CurrentUser has 0 certificates currently in the store.  This is pre any thumbprint filtering.

As I said, this has been working for the last 1-2 years, but the new certificate is now causing it to fail.  I attempted to look at a couple other stores, they had certificates in them, but none of them had my Thumbprint. [40 in Root,CurrentUser] [9 in My,LocalMachine].

I am using a code equivalent to the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code

Edit: noteworthy, this all works fine on my local computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certificate not found on Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457686/certificate-not-found-on-azure-web-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at my company found the following Stack Overflow post that talks about WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES configruation being a wildcard entry.

This fixed my problem.

[Certificate not found on Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457686/certificate-not-found-on-azure-web-app)