# Azure web app "ERR: Cert with thumbprint: ...' not found in local machine cert store."

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, push-notification

I'm trying to use an Apple push certificate in an Asp.NET Core 1.1 app but it cannot find any certificates.

I uploaded the cert and set WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES to *(all).

The following code is what I use to get the certificate

```
  var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
  try
  {
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

      var certCollection = store.Certificates;
      var signingCert = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
      if (signingCert.Count == 0)
      {
          throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("Cert with thumbprint: '{0}' not found in local machine cert store.", thumbprint));
      }
      return signingCert[0];
 }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried it with `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`? That's what I have to do in Azure to access the installed certificates of my Apps. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827884/accessing-uploaded-certificates-in-azure-web-sites#answer-27819926).

Comment: Yes, same thing

Comment: What happens when you set `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` to the thumbprint instead of a wildcard?

Comment: Nothing, same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'd like to [upload your certificate to the certificates collection in Azure Websites and consume it in your web application from your site’s personal certificate store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/). I'm upload my certificate and use the following code to consume it in Asp.NET Core 1.1 app, the code works for me.

```
X509Certificate2 retVal = null;

var thumbprint = "{cert_thumbprint}";
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var certCollection = store.Certificates;

var signingCert = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

if (signingCert.Count > 0)
{
    retVal = signingCert[0];
}
```

***Remote debug the code and the code works fine on azure website***

[image]

Comment: But it works only in production environment, in dev still null cert.